# How to Add-AzureRmAccount using Microsoft account?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I want to use Add-AzureRmAccount with my Microsoft account credentials but I don't know how to do it. I want to create a non-interactive script that is run by the Windows task scheduler. Therefore, I cannot use the interactive log-in. I tried the following.

```
$User = "foo@bar.com"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $User, $PWord

Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Credential
```

However, it fails and I read in the documentation that using just the -Credential parameter is not supported for Microsoft account credentials.

How can I use my Microsoft account credentials with Add-AzureRmAccount?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the failure/error you have encountered?

Answer (score 1):

This is because a Microsoft account is a third party to Azure, and the login process needs a redirect through live.com to retrieve a token and it can't do this non-interactively.

Unfortunately this is a limitation that I doubt would be easily bypassed.

However if you create an Azure AD account / service principle, you can grant that account whatever permission you require. It just takes a little more work.

Comment: I started with an Azure runbook but had to realize that one of the modules I need, AzureRM.Sql, is not available in Azure Automation yet. I know that I could import the module manually, but this is not easy for me, as I do not own the subscription and have only limited permissions. Anyway, that's why I tried using a local PowerShell script and the Windows scheduler. It's a workaround I dreamed up. Too bad it doesn't work.